# Unity 5 - Audio Source - 3D rolloff without stereo pan effects

Tags: unity, audio

Somebody know if it is possible to use 3D rolloff of of an Audio Source without having stereo effects (You get a stereo pan effect depending on the position of your audio listener).

I know that I can do Spatial Beld to 2D but then the 3D rolloff stops and I would have to implement my own rolloff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody still wants to know.
Just set "Spread" to 180. This makes the audio roll off/on in volume but no stereo panning anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out there is currently (Unity 5.4) no way to to this.

I will implement it by controlling the AudioSource volume by script. I will use the set audio volume in the prefab as max volume so the AudioSource volume can still be uses to reduce the the overall volume of the AudioSource component.

There might be also a possibility to use a custom Audio Spatializer but from the first look ist was more complicated.